# Add information to HTML table with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, html

I am trying to get the numerical and percentage outputs of free together in a table, which I send to myself per mail. I have tried to combine these into one table for quite a while, but nothing seems to work as I think it should.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/opt/someApp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
date="date +%Y%m%d"
file="/usr/local/bin/log/start-info_`$date`.txt"

touch $file
free | awk '/Mem/{printf("Mem: %.1f% "), $3/($2+.0000000001)*100} /Swap/{printf("Swap: %.1f%"), $3/($2+.0000000001)*100}' > /usr/local/bin/test-file.txt
percent=$(cat /usr/local/bin/test-file.txt)
percent="$(echo $percent)"

free -m | awk 'BEGIN{ print("<table border=1>")}
{
print "<tr>"
for ( i = 1; i<=NF ; i++ ) {
printf "<td> %s </td> ", $i
}
printf "<td> %s </td> ", $percent;
print "</tr>"
}
END{
print("</table>")
}' > $file

sed -i 's:<td> total:<td> </td> <td> total:' $file

(
 echo "To: myself@example.com"
 echo "From: server@example.com"
 echo "Subject: startinformation server"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html charset=US-ASCII"
 cat $file
 echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail myself@example.com
```

The output of $percent isn't in the mail, it just repeats the previous data in a single cell.

[image]

If I put the output of $percent directly into the mail with "echo $percent >> $file", then it shows correctly as "Mem: 16.0% Swap: 0.0%", but I need it to be in the table.

EDIT:
Here is an example of free -m:

```
$ free -m                                                                                                                 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3873         616         898           0        2358        2990
Swap:          3872           0        3872

$ free                                                                                                                    
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3966276      630492     1045640         956     2290144     3062460
Swap:       3965948         780     3965168
```

In the first file (which I forgot to add at first) is the HTML code:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td> </td> <td> total </td> <td> used </td> <td> free </td> <td> shared </td> <td> buff/cache </td> <td> available </td> <td>               total        used    >
<tr>
<td> Mem: </td> <td> 3873 </td> <td> 619 </td> <td> 597 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 2656 </td> <td> 2987 </td> <td> Mem:           3873         619         597      >
<tr>
<td> Swap: </td> <td> 3872 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 3872 </td> <td> Swap:          3872           0        3872 </td> </tr>
</table>
```

There is only the output of the first awk in the second file:

```
Mem: 16.0% Swap: 0.0%
```

What I'm trying to do, is get the output of the second file, so the 16.0% and 0.0%, into the table like this:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td> </td> <td> total </td> <td> used </td> <td> free </td> <td> shared </td> <td> buff/cache </td> <td> available </td> <td> %used </td> </tr>
<tr>
<td> Mem: </td> <td> 3873 </td> <td> 619 </td> <td> 597 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 2656 </td> <td> 2987 </td> <td> 16.0% </td> </tr>
<tr>
<td> Swap: </td> <td> 3872 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 3872 </td> <td> 0.0% </td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please avoid using `sudo` unless it is actually needed, that can save you from a lot of pain. `free` doesn't require any special permissions so there is no reason to run it with `sudo`.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of things in your script that just don't make sense. For example, you are getting a file's contents into a variable and then instead of just using the variable you are echoing it and saving in another. Please [edit] your question, show us the input you have (an example output of `free -m` on your system, and the contents of `/usr/local/bin/test-file.txt`—are you sure you want that in `/usr/local/bin`?) then show us the output you would like to get from that example so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @terdon it was a requirement, to have it inside of /usr/local/bin. I have added your mentioned information, I hope it helps to clear up my case a little

Comment: Thanks, but why would that be a requirement? Is this homework? Why would you even need a file at all? Why not just save the output into a variable directly.  Also, please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. We can't use the image to test our solutions.

Comment: I don't really know, why it was a requirement in the first place, but it came from some higherups at my workplace. I don't really need a file, I thought it might be easier to combine everything like that, but I normally don't work with Linux.

Comment: What is "it" in the sentence ["...to have **it** inside of /usr/local/bin"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/707092/add-information-to-html-table-with-awk#comment1338337_707092)? Surely it's the command you're creating, not any output or temp files produced by the command. `bin` directories are for executables, not log files or any other output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output of `free` as used to pipe to the first awk script to create the file containing `Mem: 16.0% Swap: 0.0%`.

Comment: The script is located in /usr/local/bin, to have a clear distinction, what is on which partition/in which directory

Comment: It doesn't matter to us where the script is located, the point @terdon and I are making is that regardless of where the script lives it shouldn't be producing output files under a bin directory.

Comment: Why are you using 2 different calls to `free` that both produce the same percentages? If you ran `awk '/Mem/{printf("Mem: %.1f% "), $3/($2+.0000000001)*100} /Swap/{printf("Swap: %.1f%"), $3/($2+.0000000001)*100}'` on the output of `free -m` it'd produce exactly the same output as running it on the output of `free` so what's the point of 2 different calls to awk on the output of 2 different calls to `free`?

Comment: Because I need to get both the output of free -m and the percentage in the table, I made in two seperate awk's. I tried to chain the two awk's together to get the output of both, but I couldn't figure out how to do it, so both the regular output and the percentage get shown. I guess it is located in the bin, because it doesn't matter, if those files get deleted, but as I mentioned, I didn't really have a say in it.

Comment: `awk` programme is quoted, so `$percent` is not what you want. 1) use `awk -v percent=$percent '...'`2) then, use `percent` not `$percent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can tell this is all you need, i.e. 1 call to `free -m`, 1 call to `awk`, and no call to `sed`:

```
free -m |
awk '
    BEGIN { print("<table border=1>") }
    {
        if ( NR == 1 ) {
            $0 = "_" FS $0 FS "%used"
            numCols = NF
            $1 = ""
        }
        else {
            $numCols = sprintf("%0.1f%%", ($2 ? ($3 / $2) * 100 : 0))
        }
        print "<tr>"
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            printf "<td>%s</td>%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        print "</tr>"
    }
    END { print "</table>" }
'
```

Given the output of `free -m` you provided, the above will output:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td></td> <td>total</td> <td>used</td> <td>free</td> <td>shared</td> <td>buff/cache</td> <td>available</td> <td>%used</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mem:</td> <td>3873</td> <td>616</td> <td>898</td> <td>0</td> <td>2358</td> <td>2990</td> <td>15.9%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Swap:</td> <td>3872</td> <td>0</td> <td>3872</td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td>0.0%</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Can you explain, why you used the questionmarks in the else statement?

Comment: You're welcome. `($2 ? ($3 / $2) * 100 : 0)` is just a [ternary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to ensure we don't divide by zero. It says `IF $2 is not 0 THEN (`?`) evaluate ($3 / $2) * 100 ELSE (`:`) use 0`